# Disable page transition on a single page in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm aware I could use `IonicModule.forRoot({animated: false})` to disable page transitions in app.module.ts file. However, this disables transitions and animations for the entire app.

I would like to disable only the page transition **for a specific page**. I plan to use my own custom animation to open the page: *specifically, I would like to be able to open a page with a zoom effect, just like in WhatsApp when you tap the contact name on the toolbar of the conversation screen.* Every other page should retain the default transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using 2 steps

1. Firstly disable it globally

*app.moduel.ts*

```
IonicModule.forRoot({animated: false})
```

2. Then use [Native Page Transitions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-page-transitions) plugin to add the transition as you wish for the pages that you need.

The above 2 steps will be worked for the native devices since it requires a native plugin. But if you need to support this for both platforms(i.e. web and real device) using the same code base then you need to choose Angular [Route transition animations](https://angular.io/guide/route-animations).

i.e.

1. You need to do 1st step above
2. Use Angular Route transition animations for all the pages where you need animations

Comment: Sounds like a great solution. However, if I'm not wrong, this plugin only works on real devices but not on browsers such as Chrome etc.

Comment: How can I achieve the same on browsers as well then? The app I'm doing this in has both native and web versions.

Comment: You can use `Route transition animations` for that: https://angular.io/guide/route-animations

Comment: Can you please update your answer to clarify this a little bit more? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I will accept this answer since the sequence of steps is now clear and easy to follow.